# python find all best matching arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to build a matching service like below. Basically, it finds all best matching arrays in `foods`. I tried to use below code but it was too slow on >= 50 million rows. I want the result in 60 secs but I couldn't think of any better algorithm. Below is my code that I used for 11 records.

```py
import numpy as np

result = set()

foods = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [2, 9, 5, 3, 10],
    [1, 2, 5, 10, 2],
    [2, 10, 9, 3, 6],
    [10, 3, 4, 6, 7],
    [6, 2, 4, 3, 5],
    [3, 10, 9, 8, 7],
    [2, 9, 5, 3, 1],
    [8, 6, 3, 2, 5],
    [1, 7, 8, 9, 10],
]

foods = [np.array(sorted([f for f in food])) for food in foods]


best_simularity = -1
for base_idx, base_food in enumerate(foods):
    for target_idx, target_food in enumerate(foods[base_idx+1:]):

        sim = len(np.intersect1d(base_food, target_food))
        if sim < best_simularity:
            continue

        if sim > best_simularity:
            result = set()

        result.add(f'{base_idx+1}-{base_idx+1+target_idx+1}')
        best_simularity = sim

# Expecting 
# 4 1-9, 2-8, 3-9, 7-10, 1-7, 2-11, 3-5, 8-11
print(f"{best_simularity}", ", ".join(list(result)))
```

Comment: what u are doing takes n^2 time complexity, as u are comparing each array with every other array. U may need to consider to represent each array with a constant time representation, like a mean and a standard deviation. Alternatively consider building some similarity sorting procedures as u append new entry into the list so each addition/searching takes log(n) time.

Comment: Best matching with what?

Comment: @chrisckwong821thxs! I'll give a look at it

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I want to find best matching arrays inside 2D foods array. For example, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` has best matches with `[2, 9, 5, 3, 1]` and `[6, 2, 4, 3, 5]` since it has four equal values.

Comment: For each array, you want to find the others that have the maximum number of common element? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-programming-classics-the-longest-common-subsequence/problem

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, it's close to it. I figured out how to get common subsequences using numpy. But I still don't get how to iterate through >= 50million rows quick enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to speed up the code considerably (x40) using `numba`. I also changed the code to return a list of tuples instead of a string:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

# generate (100 x 5) foods, with values between 0 and 15
foods = np.random.randint(0, 15, (200, 5))
# calculate unique values to speed up processing
foods = [np.unique(x) for x in foods]

def sim_foods(foods):
    result = []
    best_simularity = -1
    for base_idx, base_food in enumerate(foods):
        for target_idx, target_food in enumerate(foods[base_idx+1:]):

            sim = len(np.intersect1d(base_food, target_food))
            if sim < best_simularity:
                continue

            if sim > best_simularity:
                best_simularity = sim
                result = []

            result.append((base_idx, base_idx+target_idx+1))
    return result

@numba.njit
def sim_foods_numba(foods):
    rows = len(foods)
    # this is a 'trick' to tell numba the result shall be a list of 2-tuples
    result = [(0,0)] 
    best_simularity = -1

    for base_idx in range(rows):
        for target_idx in range(base_idx+1, rows):
            sim_c = np.bincount(np.hstack((foods[base_idx], foods[target_idx])))
            sim = np.sum(sim_c > 1)
            if sim < best_simularity:
                continue

            if sim > best_simularity:
                best_simularity = sim
                result = [(0,0)]

            result.append((base_idx, target_idx,))

    # drop the (0,0) tuple at the front
    return result[1:]

print(sim_foods(foods) == sim_foods_numba(foods))
# True
```

Performance comparison:

```
%timeit sim_foods(foods)
1 loop, best of 5: 408 ms per loop

# numba has compilation overhead, so the first run will be much slower
%timeit sim_foods_numba(foods)
The slowest run took 52.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 5: 10.5 ms per loop
```

This will still be tremendously slow for millions of foods, though, since it's still O(n²), but this will allow your food list to be about 6 times longer (6² = 36) than your previous algorithm allowed.

Some more performance (~ x number of cores) can be gained by parallelizing the inner loop, by aggregating all lengths and discarding all but the longest one at the end of the inner loop, instead of at every iteration. This comes at the cost of increased memory overhead, so parallelizing the outer loop as well will probably push you into memory problems. For a 32 core threadripper machine you can then gain about a factor of 20-30 speedup again, so another list size increase of a factor of 4-5. So in total I see about a factor of 1000x of speedup potential by optimization, but since the algorithm is O(n²), that is still not much, I guess you need another factor of 1000x?

Maybe you can squeeze out some more performance by using Fortran, C or Julia, but again, the underlying algorithm itself will not improve.

Comment: Thx for amazing answer. I tried on expensive aws spot instance and it worked better!!